# NLTK applied to dataframes , how to iterate through list

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, nltk, tokenize, pos-tagger

Apologies in advance as this is my first question. I am using nltk to tokenize a series of tweets from a csv that I have loaded into a df. The tokenization works fine and outputs something like this [[My, uncle, ...]] into a cell in a df. I want to then apply a POS tagger to the tokenized text for the whole column of the df. I use the code below to do it. The line I am having difficulty with is `df['tagged'] = df['tokenized'].apply(lambda row: [nltk.pos_tag(row) for item in row])`. I know that I am iterating on the wrong element (row versus item) but can't figure out the correct way to do it. The code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize,wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
read_test = pd.read_csv("simontwittertest.csv")
df = read_test
df['tokenized'] = df['content'].apply(lambda row:    [nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(row) for item in row])
df['tagged'] = df['tokenized'].apply(lambda row: [nltk.pos_tag(row) for item in row])
print(df['tagged'])`
```

Out of interest I found a small bug with pos_tag which only works with NLTK 3.1 not NLTK 3.2 (at least with Python 2.7)
Many Thanks`

Comment: It might be easier to work with `sframe` too, see https://github.com/dato-code/SFrame/issues/16#issuecomment-185326257

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying a lambda function to a row, you need to specify `axis=1`:

```
df['tokenized'] = df['content'].apply(
    lambda row: [nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(row) for item in row], axis=1)
df['tagged'] = df['tokenized'].apply(
    lambda row: [nltk.pos_tag(row) for item in row], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried this already but I'll have another go!